# Why is mycli history file appearing in home directory?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, command-line, logging

I started using [mycli](https://github.com/dbcli/mycli) and want `$HOME/.mycli-history` to be generated and updated from `$HOME/.cache/mycli/.mycli-history`

1. Moved `$HOME/.myclirc` -> `~/.config/mycli/.myclirc`
2. Created `alias mycli='sudo mycli --myclirc ~/.config/mycli/.myclirc'`
3. Updated `log_file = ~/.cache/mycli/.mycli.log` in `.myclirc`
4. Moved `$HOME/.mycli.log` to `~/.cache/mycli/.mycli.log`

These steps were successful for the rc and log files. I did not get much from searching online or their Documentation, but saw [this answer](https://github.com/dbcli/mycli/issues/647#issue-357617425) and added `export MYCLI_HISTFILE="~/.cache/mycli/.mycli-history"` to my `.zshrc`. After restarting my shell, my history file is still being populated in `$HOME`.

Is there any command line flag, environment variable, or configuration that can change this? If not, would my only option be to symlink it?

Using mycli v1.27.0 in zsh on MacOS Sonoma 14.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have `sudo` in your alias? That seems wrong.

In fact, looking at the [source code](https://github.com/dbcli/mycli/blob/8c005f7c9923e3502a5b06def28178e53f07ee80/mycli/main.py#L624C24-L624C43), `sudo` will result in `mycli` looking for a file inside the root user's home directory rather than your own.

Or at least that is how `os.path.expanduser()` behaves when testing on my Linux machine.

Comment: Thanks for this, and I agree this is most likely the issue! When I run `mycli --myclirc ~/.config/mycli/.myclirc` without sudo I get `(1045, "Access denied for user 'mubuntu'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")`. Suggestions on how to debug?

Comment: @VivekJha Your MariaDB root account will be used when you use `sudo` and this probably has `unix_socket` auth, so that is why that works. Without sudo: Use the root account with `mysql_native_password` auth + a password. Since MariaDB 10.4, a user can have multiple auth mechanisms. Chances are, your root account is already set up for this, so all you have to do is [set a password](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/set-password/) for the root acccount and then put the credentials in a minimal `~/.my.cnf` file (you just need a `[client]` section with `user`, `password` and maybe `port` ).

Comment: Thanks this worked! I already had a mysql instance running so i killed it and initialized a database setting password for root user. I then logged in as root, created my user, granted privileges, and tested. By adding `MYSQL_HISTFILE=~/.cache/mysql/.mysql_history` and  `MYCLI_HISTFILE=~/.cache/mycli/.mycli-history` to my `.zshrc` this was the final step needed